# Any Javascript/Jquery Library To validate SQL statment?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, sql

i have a textarea in my project where users can save SQL queries but one of the requirements is to check if this query is valid or not

**EXAMPLE**

if user entered something like :

```
SELECT ** FROM EMP
```

this should return false and an error message just saying `invalid` it doesn't have to give any reasons

mainly the queries will be just `select` statement

*NOTICE*
i DON'T want to use any server side at this point

**Question**

Does any one knows a javascript / jquery  library or plugin that have this functionality or any thing similar

i have Google this and it didn't show any thing

Thanks

Comment: Did you Google 'javascript sql parser'? I just found this: https://github.com/forward/sql-parser

Comment: Does the parser need to know about your database? i.e. Which tables/views you have?

Comment: It would be far better to let the database engine figure this out for you.  I wonder if there is a way to do a dry run of a query... see if the query compiles but not execute it...

Comment: No it doesn't have too ... i don't think javascript can do this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example fiddle using the [JS SQL Parser](https://github.com/forward/sql-parser):

http://jsfiddle.net/Hb6az/

The parser will throw an error if it hits something unexpected, so you have to wrap your checking code in a `try {} catch(error) {}` block.

Comment: Note from the description: "Currently it is only capable of parsing fairly basic SELECT queries"

Comment: it looks good but as @MichaelMior said it parse basic SELECT queries see http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/Hb6az/1/

Comment: Try it from your local machine, it looks like jsFiddle is having trouble with the external resource and SQLParser is not getting defined.

Comment: @Laurence - I tried installing JS SQL Parser from localhost WAMP server. I couldn't find working. Is there a better way to make it work?

Comment: @ronquiq I have not used this in a very long time but it was an NPM package, you'd need to install it with `npm` or `yarn`