# Javascript Regex get list of string not in single or double quotes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex

Guy I have a list of string.

```
Select 
id AS "cusId ",
name as 'cusName', gendar as ' Gendar.',
isPaid as " is'Paid ", total, remarks FROM
```

I need a regex that returns:

```
Select
id
name
gendar
isPaid
total
remarks
FROM
```

And also ignore comma and 'AS' keyword.

So far from PHP I can use `preg_match_all('/(?<![\S"])([^"\'\s]+)(?![\S"])/')` and filter all query keywords later on, but came to JavaScript there is no lookbehind in regex.

Comment: Why `Select id name isPaid` and not `Select id name gender isPaid`? You'd better clarify your requirements.

Comment: @revo sorry i miss out that

Comment: I guess the question formatting was wrong. If not, please let know. See [*How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for telling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER: The solution below is by no means a generic solution for parsing arbitrary SQL queries. To parse arbitrary SQL queries, you need to build or use an existing one. See also [*How to parse / tokenize an SQL statement in Node.js*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25156505/how-to-parse-tokenize-an-sql-statement-in-node-js)**.

So, taking into account ***your* specific input strings**, you can use a regex that will match what you do not need, and then will capture what you need:

```
/"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|\s+AS\s+|\s*((?:(?!\sAS\s)[^,\s])+)/gi
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eD8jR1/2)

**Explanation**:

- `"[^"]*"` - match a double-quoted substring that has no `"` inside (replace with `"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"` if you need to support escaped `"` inside)
- `|` - or
- `'[^']*'` - match single-quoted substring having no `'` inside (replace with `'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'` if you need to support escaped `'` inside)
- `|` - or
- `\s+AS\s+` - "AS" word inside 1+ whitespaces
- `|` - or
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `((?:(?!\sAS\s)[^,\s])+)` - Group 1 capturing one or more symbols other than `,` and whitespace (see `[^,\s])+`) that are not starting a sequence of a whitespace + `AS` + whitespace. It matches any text that is not `space`+`AS`+`space`.

JS demo:

```js
var re = /"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|\s+AS\s+|\s*((?:(?!\sAS\s)[^,\s])+)/gi; 
var str = 'Select id AS "cusId ", name as \'cusName\', gendar as \' Gendar.\', isPaid as " is\'Paid " total , datetime FROM';
var res = [];
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m[1]) { 
        res.push(m[1]); // Add the Capture group 1 to the resulting array
    }
}
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```

Comment: I have re-checked the source of your question and it seems you need to get `Select` and `id` separated, right? Then, you should replace `[^,]` with `[^,\s]`. See https://regex101.com/r/eD8jR1/2

Comment: wow, excellent  , time to study regex again , hopefully one day become regex master like you : )  thanks dude

Comment: Sorry, but do you need `[    "Select", "id", "name", "gendar", "isPaid", "total", "datetime", "FROM" ]` with the input like `Select id AS "cusId ", name as 'cusName', gendar as ' Gendar.', isPaid as " is'Paid " total , datetime FROM`? I think you do, I updated the answer.

Comment: Are you trying to provide a regex to work with SQL queries in general or just with that only one OP's sample?

Comment: If it is a question to me, I am not providing a general regex for SQL queries, this is impossible to do with just a small regex like this. There are specific requirements in the question, that is what my regex is designed for.

Comment: As per question's title, *strings not between quotes*, you are trying to provide a regex to work with SQL queries in general which OP himself threw one type of PCRE regex for it already: `(?<![\S"])([^"\'\s]+)(?![\S"])` and it [almost works](https://regex101.com/r/eD8jR1/3) but [yours doesn't](https://regex101.com/r/eD8jR1/4). If you're going to reply, please mention me.

Comment: @revo: I never mentioned this is a generic pattern. Only the one that matches OP's specific sample input. I would not post a regex answer for a request to parse arbitrary SQL queries. We have  a C# SQL query parser at work, and it is very comprehensive, I know what this all means.

Comment: Yes, and you never mentioned it is not. I think it is considered *good* if you update your answer with an explicit point to this.

Comment: I added the disclaimer with a reference to the SO thread discussing ways to parse SQL queries.

Comment: GJ, now to me it makes sense.